# Couchbase GUI for exploring data

Tags: tools, couchbase

Is there GUI for `Couchbase` to explore data (especially views), similar to `PGAdmin 3` or `MySQL Workbench` or `RoboMongo`

**EDIT**: ah, I found the button mentioned by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484591/alternate-couchbase-ui)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else comes across this needing help... the Couchbase UI is both command line and web-based, the latter of which is typically running on port 8091.

So, for example, if you've installed it on your computer, it would be `http://localhost:8091/`

If Couchbase is installed elsewhere, say IP `192.168.1.101`, it would be `http://192.168.1.101:8091`

This is covered in the [Couchbase 3.x post-install tasks](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/post-install.html) as well as [the post-install tasks for Couchbase 4.x](http://docs.couchbase.com/4.0/getting-started/set-up-couchbase.html).

[image: Couchbase 4 Web UI]

Comment: Yes, the only thing is if you need to update documents, sometimes the Administration Console it's not the best fit.